# Difference in memory location that is used for const char pointer and one that is used for dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

Is the memory location that is used for const char pointer and one that is used for dynamic memory allocation different?

For example, when you do

```
const char* city = "Paris";
```

and

```
char city[6] = "Paris";
char* c = new char[strlen(city) + 1];
```

Both city and c have the value of "Paris", but do they use a different type of memory to store those values?

Comment: Thet typically are, but there is no requirement.  This sounds like an XY problem.  What use will this information provide?  What are you trying to accomplish after knowing this?

Comment: "Both city and c have the value of "Paris"" no they dont.

Comment: @NathanOliver
I was initially trying to figure out how exactly DMA works. Usually it is used when you don't know exact size of an array before compiling. However, looking at the example of using DMA, you can use const char* for assigning a string and you don't need to specify the size of the string unlike char array and I'm confused why we need to specify the size of the string using DMA for const char* type of variable. With this confusion, I was working on ABC array of pointers. To understand this, I thouguht I need to know how exactly DMA works first.

Comment: Yes const data may be placed in read-only memory/data segment or page.
Side note, in C++ don't use `new char` just use std::string (it will do this dynamic memory allocation and more importantly de-allocation for you).

Comment: DMA means "Direct Memory Access" not "Dynamic memory allocation".

Comment: @PepjinKramer for a string of this size `std::string` will probably not do any dyanmic allocation, but sso

Comment: *DMA means "Direct Memory Access"* --  It seems to be a trend for new programmers to use acronyms that do not match what is known to the rest of the computer world, and then the new programmer doesn't read the tag that just by concidence matches their wrong assumptions.  For example "dsa" to mean "data structures and algorithms", and now "dma" to mean "dynamic memory allocation".  @OP -- Please read the tags when applying it to your question.  Persons interested in Direct Memory Access (`dma`) now will have your question show up in their list.

Comment: Don’t forget the `delete[] c;`. Usually the `city[6]` will be on a stack, unless it’s a global variable. In a traditional single-threaded program, a stack will be at a high address (above the address space hole, if the platform has one) and grows downward. The dynamically allocated array will be on the heap, which is often below the address space hole and (as long as nothing is deallocated) grows upward.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* city = "Paris";
```

Most likely in read only memory

```
char city[6] = "Paris";
```

Static storage (stack or global variable)

```
char* c = new char[strlen(city) + 1];
```

Stored on heap/free store (so needs to be `delete`ed)